# Table of Equations

Tags: table-of-contents, equations

I've looked around for this, and haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer; How would one go about producing (automatically) a table of equations, just a numbered list of used equations, possibly linked to their position in the document, as say an appendix?

Comment: Do you want the list to contain for each numbered equation, the equation *number* and the page, or the entire *equation* and the page?

Comment: Not to be absurd, but it'd be nice to know how to do all three! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the [`tocloft`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft?lang=en) package you can create your own *List of ...* list. [Here](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/) is a nice tutorial.

Comment: Does that work for non-floating content?

Comment: I think so. At the moment I don't have time to try it out

Answer (score 3):

The [`thmtools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools?lang=en) package defines `\listoftheorems` which does pretty much what you want. See page 7 of the manual.

(Disclaimer: I've not actually used it, but I've seen it recommended on here before.)

Comment: I just realised that the question was about _equations_ not theorems, but I'll leave it up here in case there is a way to do what is wanted via thmtools...

Comment: Completely acceptable, cheers, that's a tangential question that's nice to have answered.