# List of Equations / Table of Equations

Tags: equations, table-of-contents, tocloft

After finding [Table of Equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4954/table-of-equations) and http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=428, I set about making a *List of Equations* for my document. The catch here is that we already have a working draft and its hundreds of pages and contains dozens of equations.

The above links describe how to use **tocloft** to add the *List of Equations*, but both require following each equation with a tag such as `\myequations{Display name}`. To avoid having to add this for all of our equations, I redefined `equation` to automatically include our `\myequations{}` command:

```
\let\oldequation = \equation
\let\endoldequation = \endequation
\renewenvironment{equation}{
    \begin{oldequation}
}{
    \end{oldequation}
    \myequations{\@currentlabelname}
}
```

I proceeded with the **tocloft**-specific code which is directly based on the above links, ending with:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}

% myequation takes in its display name
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{

% display name is printed
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
```

Then all `\equation`s will appear automatically in the *List of Equations*. That's great, but there is one ***problem***:

---

Each `\equation`s displayed name in the *List of Equations* is not its own `\label` (eg. "Torque") but instead is the name of the `\subsection` in which it appears (such that dozens of equations have the name of "DC Motor Operation," etc.)

---

Any ideas? What can I replace `\@currentlabelname` with to drop in the name of the `\label` for the equation? A simple one looks like this:

```
\begin{equation}
\tau=F\times r
\label{eq:Torque}
\end{equation}
```

FWIW, I am actually doing this in Lyx but that doesn't seem to be the source of my problems. In fact, if there is a more elegant solution for Lyx, I'm all ears.

Thanks!

### Example in LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% we use this for our refernces as well
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}

% redefinition of \equation for convenience
\let\oldequation = \equation
\let\endoldequation = \endequation
\renewenvironment{equation}{
\begin{oldequation}
}{
\end{oldequation}
\myequations{\@currentlabelname}
}

% try to make a List of Equations, 
% error is most likely in the @currentlabelname above
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations} 
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname} 
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{ 
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{3em}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\listofmyequations

\section{Brushless Motor Fundamentals}
\subsubsection{DC Motor Operation}
Torque is generated in DC motors from the magnetic force, 
also known as the Lorentz force, which is produced when an
electric current is passed through a coil in a magnetic field. 
This force is given by \ref{eq:Force}.

\begin{equation}
F=q[E+(v\times B)]
\label{eq:Force}
\end{equation}
where F is the force perpendicular to the coil, 
E is the electric field in the coil, 
v is the velocity of the charged particles in the coil, 
and B is the magnetic field. From mechanics, torque is 

\begin{equation}
\tau=F\times r\label{eq:Torque}\end{equation}
If the electrical force in \ref{eq:Force} is ignored, 
and the remaining magnetic force is used in \ref{eq:Torque}, 
with the assumption that v is perpendicular to B, we find that
\begin{equation}
\tau=qvBrsin\theta
\label{eq:Magnetic}\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[FIXED - Thank you **Mike Renfro**] Equations 2.1 - 2.9 display correctly in the *List of Equations* but after the equation number hits 2.10 the last digit ('ones' digit) overlaps with the  beginning of the display name.

Comment: let me see if I understand your problem: you want to use the string that you write in the argument of `\label` as the entry for the new list of equations, but stripping out the `eq:` prefix used in `\label`? For example, if you have `\label{eq:Torque}` then just `Torque` should be placed in the list of equations?

Comment: below I added a solution which removes "eq:" from the new list.

Comment: Would it be possible (how?) to refer to an (optional) `\caption` for equations?  Because purpose of `\label` is kind of different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a modified version of Lev Bishop's code; I used the [xstring](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xstring) package to remove the string "eq:" from the labels:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% we use this for our refernces as well
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}

% redefinition of \equation for convenience
\let\oldequation = \equation
\let\endoldequation = \endequation
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldlabel = \label}% \AtBeginDocument because hyperref redefines \label
\newcommand{\mynewlabel}[1]{%
  \StrBehind{#1}{eq:}[\Str]% remove "eq:" from labels
  \myequations{\Str}\oldlabel{#1}}
  \renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \oldequation
  \let\label\mynewlabel
}{\endoldequation}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
      \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{3em}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofmyequations

\section{Brushless Motor Fundamentals}
\subsubsection{DC Motor Operation}
Torque is generated in DC motors from the magnetic force,
also known as the Lorentz force, which is produced when an
electric current is passed through a coil in a magnetic field.
This force is given by \ref{eq:Force}.
\begin{equation}
  F=q[E+(v\times B)]
  \label{eq:Force}
\end{equation}
where $F$ is the force perpendicular to the coil,
$E$ is the electric field in the coil,
$v$ is the velocity of the charged particles in the coil,
and $B$ is the magnetic field. From mechanics, torque is
\begin{equation}
  \tau=F\times r
  \label{eq:Torque}
\end{equation}
If the electrical force in \ref{eq:Force} is ignored,
and the remaining magnetic force is used in \ref{eq:Torque},
with the assumption that $v$ is perpendicular to $B$, we find that
\begin{equation}
      \tau=qvBrsin\theta
  \label{eq:Magnetic}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This doesn't work when you use underscores in your labels. It results in an error for the first equation using underscores in its label:
`! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   _
<argument> ...stname }{\numberline {2.1.1}example_
                                                  matrix_universe}\hyper@lin...

\l@myequations ...\@nameuse {cftmyequationsfont}#1
                                                  }\nobreak \@nameuse {cftmy...

...`

The error message goes on for a bit more. It's too long for a comment. How to fix?

Comment: Also it's not really a missing `$` in the document. I checked, when I don't use your list of enumerations, the error does not occur.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a modified version of your example. The main change is that I redefine `\label` within equation environments:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[unicode=true, pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

% we use this for our refernces as well
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}

% redefinition of \equation for convenience
\let\oldequation = \equation
\let\endoldequation = \endequation
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldlabel = \label}% \AtBeginDocument because hyperref redefines \label
\newcommand{\mynewlabel}[1]{\myequations{#1}\oldlabel{#1}}
\renewenvironment{equation}{%
\oldequation
\let\label\mynewlabel
}{\endoldequation}

% try to make a List of Equations,
% error is most likely in the @currentlabelname above
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{3em}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}
\listofmyequations

\section{Brushless Motor Fundamentals}
\subsubsection{DC Motor Operation}
Torque is generated in DC motors from the magnetic force,
also known as the Lorentz force, which is produced when an
electric current is passed through a coil in a magnetic field.
This force is given by \ref{eq:Force}.

\begin{equation}
F=q[E+(v\times B)]
\label{eq:Force}
\end{equation}
where F is the force perpendicular to the coil,
E is the electric field in the coil,
v is the velocity of the charged particles in the coil,
and B is the magnetic field. From mechanics, torque is

\begin{equation}
\tau=F\times r\label{eq:Torque}\end{equation}
If the electrical force in \ref{eq:Force} is ignored,
and the remaining magnetic force is used in \ref{eq:Torque},
with the assumption that v is perpendicular to B, we find that
\begin{equation}
\tau=qvBrsin\theta
\label{eq:Magnetic}\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using TexMaker this builds fine but the output shows "Contents" (so far so good) then "List of Equations" (warmer...) and then skips right to the first section, "Brushless Motor Fundamentals," without displaying any of the equations in the list :-(

Comment: Compile it twice? Any error messages in log file?

Comment: Good catch---compiling it twice it definitely works. Now I just need to figure out how to remove the "eq:", if that's even possible.

Answer (score 3):

I expanded upon the previous answers to define a command that you can use like so:

```
\noteworthy{a^2 + b^2 = c^2}{Pythagorean theorem}
```

And it will automatically label, reference, box, and list the equations that I consider noteworthy. I'm really happy with the result.

Note that the red squares just highlight hyperlinks, they're not visible on the pdf.

[image]

And then the equation is numbered, boxed, labelled with text (that matches the list of equations), and gets a label to allow us to reference it.

[image]

Minimum viable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}    % for list of equations
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % to undo \centering
\usepackage{hyperref}   % to make references hyperlinks
\usepackage{glossaries} 

% define list of equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{\Large{List of Equations}}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{
   \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}
}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.3em}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsindent}{1.5em}

% command to box, label, reference, and 
% include noteworthy equation in list of equations
\newcommand{\noteworthy}[2]{
\begin{align} \label{#2} \ensuremath{\boxed{#1}} \end{align} 
\myequations{#2} \centering \small \textit{#2} \normalsize \justify }

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations \pagebreak

\noteworthy{P(\bigcup_{n=1}^n A_n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^n P(A_n)}{Boole's inequality}

Where the events $A_n$ are disjoint, then the inequality 
in equation \ref{Boole's inequality} becomes an equality.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't come up with a minimal working example in regular LaTeX yet.

As for (2), try setting `\cftmyequationsnumwidth` to a larger value (see tocloft manual, section 2.3).

Comment: is there any way to attach a minimal working example?

Comment: @gnirts: If you have to *attach* the example, it's not minimal. ;-)

Comment: I added \setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{3em} and that works great, thank you! I also updated the original post with a working example