# LaTeX error: missing $

Tags: math-mode

I have some math equations within my LaTeX file and I usually denote these with `$` to enter math mode. For longer equations, I will use `\begin{math} ...` but for some reason this is giving me an error telling me I am missing a `$`.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{math}
\example{ \Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S }
\label{1st_ex}
\end{math}
\end{center}
```

gives me

```
Missing $ inserted <inserted text> $ l.302 \example {\Delta ....
```

Even if I insert `$` it still gives me that error.

The example function is

```
%list of equations
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listexamplename}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{example}{exp}{\listexamplename}
\newcommand{\example}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{example}
\par\noindent\text{Equation \theexample. #1}
\addcontentsline{exp}{example}
{\protect\numberline{\thechapter.\theexample}#1}\par}
```

Comment: How is the \example command defined?

Comment: `$ ... $` is just a shorthand for `\begin{math} ... \end{math}`. For a displayed, numbered, equation, use `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`.

Comment: Please _always_ post complete (small) documents that show all relevant definitions. `\example` is not a standard command. So we do not know how it is defined If it makes a box like `\mbox` then the argument of the macro is always set in text mode and you'd need nested `$` to use `\Delta`. However `math` in `center` looks very strange markup. It should be a display math environment such as `equation` as Torbjørn says.

Answer (score 2):

Based solely in the information available in your question, I'll say you have three possible ways to write the equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S 
\label{eq:1st_ex}
\end{equation}

$\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S $

\[\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S \]

\end{document}
```

Which will produce an output like this:

[image]

Comment: Actually, you can also use `$$` (TeX-equivalent of `\[`/`\]`), `\(`/`\)` (LaTeX for `$`) or one of the `math` and `displaymath` environment. [Mathematics environments](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics#Mathematics_environments)

Comment: @ExP `$$` is not supported in LaTeX

Comment: @DavidCarlisle are you sure? I'm using it all the time ever since I began using LaTeX years ago.

Comment: @ExP yes as in: if you report a bug in latex using `$$` it'll come to me (and others) and we'll say don't use `$$`. "not supported" isn't the same as "doesn't work" It mostly works most of the time. The wiki page you referenced gives some of the reasons why it shouldn't be used. `fleqn` doesn't work also if you use `$$`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks a lot. I was not aware of this; I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: The reason I use center is because I want to center my equation, if I remove it and use begin equation then its no longer centered. Also I'm using toclof to create a list of equations so that numbers them for me ... so if I use \begin{equation*} it still gives me the $ error.

Comment: @CarlWright, It shouldn't as long as it is as I showed in my example.  That's why so many people asked a complete Minimal Working Example

Comment: The $ - $ worked perfectly so I used them. The \example function I have is to make a numbered list of equations using \toclof , I've added the code to the main post. That is now giving me an error saying undefined control sequence ' \par\noindent\text{Equation \theexample. #1}'

Comment: the `equation` environment automatically numerates all the equations.  See the picture from my answer.  You can look for more information about a table of equations here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14317/list-of-equations-table-of-equations