# List of theorems with thmtools not working - Missing \endcsname inserted

Tags: theorems, thmtools

I am trying to generate a list of all equations in a document. I have searched and it seemed a good solution would be to use the `thmtools`, which can generate a list of all theorems(if im correct). What I am looking for is (in the following example, at the chapter CheatSheet) a list with the contents of all equate-theorems, as such (with LaTeX formatting):

```
$Some_{Lowtext}$                                   (1)
$Some^{Hightext}$                                  (2)
```

Minimal (not) Working Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{theorem}
\newtheorem{equate}{}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Equations}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{Name of Chapter}
\section{Name of Section}
\subsection{Name of SubSection}
sometext
\begin{equate}
$Some_{Lowtext}$
\end{equate}
    Some other Text
\begin{equate}
$Some^{Hightext}$
\end{equate}
    And some more

\chapter{CheatSheet}

\listoftheorems

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following errors (line 24 is the line after `\listoftheorems`):

```
test.tex:24: Missing \endcsname inserted. []
test.tex:24: Too many }'s. []
```

I am wondering if this is the way to produce such a list and how I can solve my error.

Comment: At first sight, using both the `theorem` and `thmtools` packages seems to be a bad idea, as they are likely incompatible. Those two packages use different macros to define theorems: `theorem` uses `\newtheorem` whereas `thmtools` provides `\declaretheorem`. If you only load `thmtools` (not `theorem`) and use `\declaretheorem` to define your theorems, `\listoftheorems` won't generate any error.

Comment: You're right about the `theorem` and `thmtools`. `\listoftheorems` does however not output the expected output, but only acts as a table of contents for equations. It seems I cannot use `thmtools` for that, am I right?

Comment: You can look at this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14317/list-of-equations-table-of-equations

Comment: @Jubobs : your comment solves the error, if you post this as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use `declaretheorem` instead of `\newtheorem`

The `theorem` and `thmtools` packages use different mechanisms for defining theorem environments: Frank Mittelbach's `theorem` package uses the LaTeX-kernel `\newtheorem` macro, whereas Ulrich Schwarz's `thmtools` package provides a `\declaretheorem` macro.

The `thmtools` package also provides a `\listoftheorems` macro, but the latter only lists the theorem environments declared with `\declaretheorem`, **not** those simply declared with `\newtheorem`. Therefore, if you want to take advantage of `\listoftheorems`, you should declare all your theorems with `thmtools`'s `\declaretheorem` and not use `\newtheorem` explicitly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem{equate}
\renewcommand{\listtheoremname}{List of Equations}

\begin{document}
\begin{equate}[Low text]
$Some_{Lowtext}$
\end{equate}
    Some other Text
\begin{equate}[High text]
$Some^{Hightext}$
\end{equate}
\listoftheorems
\end{document}
```

[image]

### More details on the errors you report

If `\declaretheorem` is not used at least once in the input file, `\listoftheorems` generates the two errors you report. Here is some minimum code that reproduces the issue:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{thmtools}
%\declaretheorem{foo}
\begin{document}
\listoftheorems
\end{document}
```

No errors are generated if the third line of the code above is uncommented. In my opinion, that behaviour is unintended and qualifies as a bug; the author should probably be notified about it.