# Accent in equation list

Tags: equations, labels, accents, tocloft

I'm need to make a list of equation in my document. I found and use the modified version of Lev Bishop's code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14317/list-of-equations-table-of-equations). Everything work until there's an accent in the equation label. I got this error message :

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
>
> \@latex@warning #1->\GenericWarning 
>                                       {\space \space \space \@spaces \@spaces ...
>
> l.38   \label{eq:équation}

I'm currently using TeXnicCenter on Windows 7 but I tried others and they all gave me the same error...
Do you have any solution ?

## Example in Latex

```
\documentclass[pdftex,a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tocloft}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\let\oldequation = \equation
\let\endoldequation = \endequation
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldlabel = \label}
\newcommand{\mynewlabel}[1]{
    \fullexpandarg
    \StrBehind{#1}{eq:}[\Str]
    \myequations{\Str}\oldlabel{#1}}
\renewenvironment{equation}{
    \oldequation
    \let\label\mynewlabel
    }{\endoldequation}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Liste d'équations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations{\hspace{15pt}\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}

 \setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{3em}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations

\begin{equation}
    2+2=4
    \label{eq:équation}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's best to avoid accented characters in labels.

Answer (score 2):

Labels should contain only ASCII characters, otherwise special characters, that are internally represented with control sequences, expand and you find terrible things in referring to such labels; if you change your label to equ:eqauation, getting rid of that é, everything will run smoothly. It is less French, but it works; after all labels should not be read by humans, but only by the typesetting engine.