# List of special items other than tables or figures?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

With `\listoftables` or `\listoffigures` Latex can generate a list of tables or figures in the document.

However, is it possible to generate a list of other things?

For example, in a long document there are more than 100 "tips from the author" messages, each is in a separate paragraph following a certain style. Is it possible by adding some tag on each "tip from the author" message, then generate a list of them at the end of the document?

Comment: I would recommend searching this site for other similar questions about, for example, how to create a "list of equations" for which there are 872 related questions (ex. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14317/list-of-equations-table-of-equations) and try to follow a similar path.

Comment: The `tocloft` package manual says how you can create a new "List of ..."

Comment: `\listof...`-commands are based on LaTeX 2e-kernel-commands `\@starttoc` and `\addcontentsline`/`\addtocontents`. If you really want to delve into details you can learn about these commands in [source2e.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/source2e.pdf), File K: ltsect.dtx Date: 2020/07/27 Version v1.1e.