# Index for Equations, Definitions, Theorems,

Tags: theorems, indexing

I'd like to create different Indexes for Equations, Definitions, Theorems, Propositions, Observations, Corollaries, Examples, Exercises. Is it possible?
For now, I don't know what MWE I must insert... . If You would answer my question, you could ask me what MWE add, and then I'll add what you'll want.
Thank you so much and Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everything except equations, if you define them as "theorem" environments, you can load `thmtools` and use the `\listoftheorems` command.

See the documentation (https://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools?lang=en) for how to filter the listing by type.

---

Listing equations have been asked several times previously on this site, the first one I found is [List of Equations / Table of Equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14317/list-of-equations-table-of-equations)