# Start counting by 1 instead of 0, list of equations

Tags: table-of-contents, equations

I have code, I didn't write and I don't understand. It works just fine, but the equation counter isn't correct in the list of equations. In the document the counter starts with 1, as I want it to. But in the list of equations the counter starts with 0.
Could someone help and tell me, what I should add to solve that problem?

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{amsmath}        
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage[inner=25mm,outer=35mm,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,]{geometry}  
\usepackage{array}  
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   
\usepackage{float}  
\selectlanguage{german}

\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{chemformula} 
\usepackage{tocloft} % eigene "list of things"
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

% redefinition of \equation for convenience
\let\oldequation = \equation
\let\endoldequation = \endequation
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldlabel = \label}
\newcommand{\mynewlabel}[1]{%
  \StrBehind{#1}{eq:}[\Str]% remove "eq:" from labels
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\myequations{\Str\noexpand\quad\expandonce{\@currentlabel}}}% add tag to the entry in the list of equations
\temp % execute the command
  \oldlabel{#1} % call the original label command
  \myequations{\Str}\oldlabel{#1}}
  \renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \oldequation
  \let\label\mynewlabel
}{\endoldequation}

%\newcommand{\listequationsname}{} %Formelverzeichnis
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
      \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{3em}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
Q(t) = Q(t_0) + \int\limits_{t_0}^{t} I(t)\ \mathrm{d}t
 \myequations{elektrische Ladung}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
R_i = {\frac {U_0 - U_l}{I_l}}
 \myequations{Innenwiderstand} %\nomenclature
\end{align}

\newpage
\listofmyequations 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please extend your code snippet to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Currently I would guess, that you've made a mistake placing your `\myequations{…}` or `\label` or … to early (before the equation counter has been increased by the corresponding equation). A minimal working example would show, what you've done and so we won't need to guess, but could see and mostly indeed help.

Comment: BTW: There are a lot of questions about list of equations. Maybe you can find *your* code and also how to use it correctly. Maybe you can even find other suggestions, that would help you.

Comment: It looks like someone inherited a lot of LaTeX code which used the protocol `\label{eq:...}` and decide to remove the `eq:` using LaTeX rather than using the editor (change all).  I would throw the whole thing out.  But mostly you need to move `\myequations` after `\oldequation`.

Comment: Welcome. // Did you check the wikibook on Latex?

Comment: If you don't have to use that specific code, then this should be a solution for your question: [Table of equations like list of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173102/123129).

Comment: And [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14317/123129) might be the source of the code.

Comment: @dexteritas The code you suggested doesn't work for me. There are 100 error messages, I think that's too difficult for me to solve. Isn't it possible to use the code I already have and change the one thing of counting from 1?

Answer (score 2):

It works with both codes if you use `equation` environment and place `\myequations` after the environment.

#### Adaptations

- commented out unused packages

#### Code 1

- based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173104/123129)

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inner=25mm,outer=35mm,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,]{geometry}  

%%gmedina solution
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}% Width of equation number in List of Equations

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    Q(t) = Q(t_0) + \int\limits_{t_0}^{t} I(t)\ \mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
\myequations{elektrische Ladung}

\begin{equation}
    R_i = {\frac {U_0 - U_l}{I_l}}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Innenwiderstand} %\nomenclature

\newpage
\listofmyequations 

\end{document}
```

#### Code 2

- based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14328/123129)

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,11pt,openright]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
%\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{amsmath}        
%\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage[inner=25mm,outer=35mm,top=20mm,bottom=30mm,]{geometry}  
%\usepackage{array}  
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}   
%\usepackage{float}  
\selectlanguage{german}

%\usepackage{siunitx}  
%\usepackage{chemformula} 
\usepackage{tocloft} % eigene "list of things"
%\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

% redefinition of \equation for convenience
\let\oldequation = \equation
\let\endoldequation = \endequation
\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldlabel = \label}
\newcommand{\mynewlabel}[1]{%
  \StrBehind{#1}{eq:}[\Str]% remove "eq:" from labels
  \edef\temp{\noexpand\myequations{\Str\noexpand\quad\expandonce{\@currentlabel}}}% add tag to the entry in the list of equations
\temp % execute the command
  \oldlabel{#1} % call the original label command
  \myequations{\Str}\oldlabel{#1}}
  \renewenvironment{equation}{%
  \oldequation
  \let\label\mynewlabel
}{\endoldequation}

%\newcommand{\listequationsname}{} %Formelverzeichnis
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
      \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{3em}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
Q(t) = Q(t_0) + \int\limits_{t_0}^{t} I(t)\ \mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
\myequations{elektrische Ladung}

\begin{equation}
R_i = {\frac {U_0 - U_l}{I_l}}
\end{equation}
\myequations{Innenwiderstand} %\nomenclature

\newpage
\listofmyequations 

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]