# Customized 'list of...'

Tags: table-of-contents, counters

I am using the [covington package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/covington) to manage my examples. I would now like to create my list of examples, right after my list of figures and tables. Is there any way to do it?

example of an example:

```
\begin{examples}
\item blabla
\end{examples}
```

Comment: Have a look at the answers [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16494/generating-lists-of-custom-environment) and see if they work for you.  I don't know whether using `covington` would change anything.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) The examples in the covington package are numbered using the equation counter, so this [Table of Equations question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4954/15925) may help you.

Comment: What should be typeset in the list of examples in the case you mention?

Answer (score 3):

The `example` environment provided by the `covington` package is a list environment with the individual items labelled via the `equation` counter.  This does not fit too well with standard solutions to this type of problem: e.g. `thmtools` works for theorem like environments instead.

The code below uses the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) package.  However, the standard set-up involves using a new counter.  I have chosen to change the counter used by the `example` environment, so these are now numbered differently from equations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{covington,tocloft}

\newcommand{\listofexamples}{List of Examples}
\newlistof{example}{lex}{\listofexamples}
\newcommand{\lentry}{\addcontentsline{lex}{example}{\protect\numberline{Example
\theexample}}}

\newcounter{examplesave}

\renewenvironment{examples}%
{%
\begin{list}{(\theexample\lentry)}%
{%
\setcounter{examplesave}{\arabic{example}}%
\usecounter{example}%        
\setcounter{example}{\arabic{examplesave}}%  
\setlength{\listparindent}{0pt}%
\def\makelabel##1{##1\hfil}%  
}%
\raggedright}%                
{\end{list}}

\renewcommand{\exampleno}{\refstepcounter{example}\theexample}

\begin{document}

\listofexample

\begin{examples}
\item An example
\item Another example
\end{examples}

\clearpage

\begin{example}
  Last example
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

The above code sets up the list of examples mechanism in the standard `tocloft` way and then provides a new version of the `example` environment with the `equation` counter replaced by an `example` counter at each instance.  The labelling command is extended to add an appropriate line to the table of examples via the `\lentry` command.  I have also included a redfinition of the only other command in the `covington` package that uses the `equation` counter for examples.

Finally, remember to run latex on such a file twice to get the correct numbering in the list of examples.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that uses the `\@starttoc` to start a new file `\jobname.exs` which stores `contentsline` information about the `example` and `examples` environment. I've borrowed some ideas from [Creating list of for \newtheoremstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51691/creating-list-of-for-newtheoremstyle)

I've used the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/etoolbox) to append `\item` with the crucial part about `\addcontentsline`, but only if it is inside an `example` or `examples` environment (we wouldn't want it to happen inside of another list such as `enumerate`, `itemize`, etc) as both are set up in terms of a `list` environment; I've set up a `bool` to check if we're inside `example` or `examples`.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{covington}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text

% this sets up \jobname.exs which will store the 
% contentslines added on each example or examples
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listexamplename{List of Examples}
\newcommand\listofexamples{%
  \section*{\listexamplename}\@starttoc{exs}}
\makeatother

% Note that the example and examples environment are defined
% in terms of a list; we test if we're inside either environment
% by setting up a boolean; note that this boolean will only 
% be local to the environment, and will be false outside of it
% so there's no need to make it false again
\newbool{inexamples}
\appto\examples{\setbool{inexamples}{true}}

% This adds a contents line to \jobname.exs
%
% this does it for each \item inside of an examples environment
\appto\item{%
    \ifbool{inexamples}{%
      % if the \item is inside \begin{examples}, then
      % update the example list
      \addcontentsline{exs}{subsection}{\theequation}%
    }%
    {%
        % otherwise do nothing
    }%
}


\begin{document}

\listofexamples

\begin{equation}
 y=mx+c 
\end{equation}

\begin{examples}
\item first
\item second
\end{examples}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\end{document}
```