# Mimicking LaTeX's "table of contents" functionality

Tags: table-of-contents, auxiliary-files

I need to mimic (= duplicate) LaTeX's "table of contents" functionality on a lower level.

Basically, I would like to learn how to write entries to the `.aux` file on the first run of `LaTeX` and include them on the second run.

How do I do that, or where can I read about this?

Comment: `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{foo}` do the trick?

Comment: Look in the source (latex.ltx + e.g. article.cls).

Comment: @RomainPicot: No, I do not want to add entries to the table of contents, but duplicate the whole functionality.

Comment: You may want to read http://texblog.org/2008/07/13/define-your-own-list-of/ and [Generating lists of custom environment.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16494/35864), [Customized 'list of…'](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84749/35864)

Comment: At a lower level? Are you looking for `etoc` or `minitoc`?

Comment: @Johannes_B: `etoc` and `minitoc` are hidding the `lower level` stuff actually

Comment: It would be really nice to have an idea what is actually to be done with this `lower level` stuff

Comment: JohnB: Could you please give feedback on the provided solutions here!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The relevant routines are `\@starttoc` and `\addcontentsline` which in turn use `\addtocontents` and `\@writefile`.

I try to explain the procedure (`toc` stands here for `toc`, `lof`, `lot` and other possible acronyms of personal `list of somethings`)

From `latex.ltx` (the LaTeX core file)

```
\def\@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
      \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}
\def\addcontentsline#1#2#3{%
  \addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{\thepage}}}
\long\def\addtocontents#1#2{%
  \protected@write\@auxout
      {\let\label\@gobble \let\index\@gobble \let\glossary\@gobble}%
      {\string\@writefile{#1}{#2}}}
\def\contentsline#1{\csname l@#1\endcsname}
```

I'll shift the `\@starttoc` explanation to the end.

We see, that `\addtocontents` is apart from the formating of the using `\contentsline` is effectively a `\string\@writefile`, i.e. this string is
written into the `.aux` file. (Side note: `\label`, `\index` and `glossary` are 'gobbled', etc. 'disabled' within the `.aux` file)

In the 2nd compilation run, this `\@writefile` finally sets its contents to the relevant `toc` file (i.e. `.toc`, `.lof`, `.lot`. etc.)

Some lines before we find the `\@writefile` command, having the `#1` as the `toc` signature.

```
\long\def\@writefile#1#2{%
  \@ifundefined{tf@#1}\relax
    {\@temptokena{#2}%
     \immediate\write\csname tf@#1\endcsname{\the\@temptokena}%
    }%
}
```

Now any `ToC` - related file is bound to a file handle named `\tf@toc` or `\tf@lof` etc, i.e. `\@writefile` tries to write to the file handle `\tf@#1` (you remember `#1` has the `toc` - extension) -- it checks first if `\tf@#1` exists and if so, stores the real content to a token `\@temptokena` which is written to `\csname tf@#1\endcsname` -- the file handle macro call has to constructed this way due to its variability (`#1 as part of the name`).

### Now back to `\@starttoc`

As long no `\@starttoc{toc}` command was given, the file handle `\tf@#1` does not exist and therefore the `\@writefile` commands in the `.aux` file does nothing.

But first, the existing `\jobname.#1` (i.e. the formatted `toc` file) is read and, unless `\nofiles` wasn't specified, the handle `\tf@#1` is generated and the old `\jobname.#1` will be 'erased' and written again, for possible new entries in following runs.

Each `\tableof...` or `\listof...` command uses `\@starttoc{toc}` etc., at least in the versions by the standard classes, e.g. from `article.cls`:

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \section*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    }
```

The `\section*` command is irrelevant here -- `\@starttoc` is the important feature!

### Back to `\@writefile`

The key tool is `\@writefile` which has two arguments. You could write basically anything to `.aux` capsuled within `\@writefile`, which in turn creates the real 'content'

Here's a little sample document (`sampletoc.tex`)

```
\documentclass{book}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{One}
\section{First}
\section{Second}
\chapter{Two}
\section{First}
\section{Second}

\end{document}
```

... and its corresponding `sampletoc.aux` file

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}One}{3}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}First}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.2}Second}{3}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {2}Two}{5}}
\@writefile{lof}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{lot}{\addvspace {10\p@ }}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.1}First}{5}}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {2.2}Second}{5}}
```

It's clear, that `\contentsline` is written literally to the `.toc` wile, while the section and page numbers are used from the very moment when the `\addcontentsline` was used (i.e. `\thesection` etc. are expanded)

### Now, this is the procedure:

- Copy the `\@starttoc` command from `latex.ltx` and change the file handle name to something different, say `\mypersonaltoc`
- Copy `\@writefile` and rename it to,say, `\@mywritefile` and change `tf@#1` to `mypersonaltoc` (without `\\`)
- Call `\addtocontents{}{your content}`

Or define your own `toc` extensions, say, `johnB` and use `\addtocontents{johnB}{your content}` and `\@starttoc{johnB}` at the appropiate place.

Comment: While perusing your answer, I might have discovered an error. "Call `\addtocontents{}{your content}` would write the original `\@writefile{}{}` to the aux and not the modified version called `\@mywritefile`. Isn't that true? By the way, this is a very useful answer you have provided.

Comment: @JonathanKomar: You're probably right. I will look and eventually change later on

Answer (score 17):

Adding to the nice answer by Christian, I'd like to mention some subtler aspects of writing in the `.aux` file.

LaTeX defines a file handle for this, which is `\@auxout`, and provides the function `\protected@write` for “safe” writing in files. This function differs from ordinary `\write` in three main aspects:

1. robust commands or `\protect`ed ones are written out literally (well, almost, but it's a minor detail);
2. the command has an additional argument, so it must be called as

   ```
   \protected@write<handle>{<settings>}{<general text>}
   ```

   (here braces denote explicit ones);
3. the code is executed in a group where `\thepage` is set to `\relax`, in addition to the `<settings>` where one can specify other commands to be passed literally to the underlying `\write` command (which will expand them during the output routine).

Note that the underlying `\write` will do expansion, so commands to be written out literally must be preceded by `\protect` (or `\string`).

Other aspects of writing to `\@auxout` to be considered are that the `.aux` file is first read as part of the `\begin{document}` routine, but in an implicit group, so if something in the file should have effect on the document it must be a global declaration.

So if one runs the following test file

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\protect\newcommand\protect\mytest{This is a test macro}}
\makeatother

\ifdefined\mytest
  Defined%
\else
  Undefined%
\fi

\end{document}
```

the `.aux` file will contain the line

```
\newcommand \mytest {This is a test macro}
```

but “Undefined” will be printed nonetheless at every run. Changing `\protect\newcommand` into `\gdef` (which doesn't need `\protect` because it's unexpandable), the second run of LaTeX on the file will print “Defined” because the `.aux` file will contain

```
\gdef \mytest {This is a test macro}
```

The `.aux` file is read in also as part of the `\end{document}` routine and this is where the `\@writefile` function performs its duty. During the first reading of the `.aux` file at `\begin{document}`, `\@writefile` is set (locally) to `\@gobbletwo`.

In particular, macros found at the upper level of the `.aux` file *must* be defined. For instance, LaTeX writes

```
\bibstyle{plain}
\bibdata{test}
```

upon finding

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}
```

in the document. However `latex.ltx` has

```
% latex.ltx, lines 6292-6293
\let\bibdata=\@gobble
\let\bibstyle=\@gobble
```

so basically the two commands in the `.aux` file are ignored, as they are just for BibTeX.

Comment: Tooooooooooooo much details ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer “Some subtler details”, not “a few”. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg If I may, what is the minor detail in the first point about `\protected@write`? (I happen to like details.)

Comment: @JonathanKomar Try `\write\@auxout{\bfseries}` and `\protected@write\@auxout{}{\bfseries}`. You'll immediately see why the latter is better.

Comment: @egreg I am not confused by the difference between `\write` and `\protected@write`, rather the minor discrepancy you mentioned between the input and output of `\protected@write` "almost" literally.

Comment: @JonathanKomar Do `\protected@write\@auxout{}{\let\bfseries\relax}` and `\protected@write\@auxout{\let\relax\relax}` Look closely.

Answer (score 5):

Although you mention the TOC functionality, you state that your goal is:

> Basically, I would like to learn how to write entries to the .aux file on the first run of LaTeX and include them on the second run.

I'll focus on this question, rather than the mysteries of the actual TOC function. Here's a simple use case that is related to the table of contents: A command that will generate a list of figures if there is one, but will do nothing otherwise. Here is a complete implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\figure{\@ifundefined{so@therearefigures}
  {\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\so@list@figures{1}}%
   \newcommand\@therearefigures{1}} {}}

\newcommand\autolistfigures{\@ifundefined{so@list@figures} {} {\listoffigures}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\autolistfigures

\section{The text}
\begin{figure}
\caption{There is a figure here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

#### Explanation

To be able to check if there will be figures, we hook the figure environment so that it writes the macro definition `\gdef\so@list@figures{1}` to the aux file the first time we make a figure. (I use the TeX command `\gdef` because it doesn't care whether its argument is already defined). To detect whether it has already done this in an earlier call, `{figure}` also defines (and checks) a second macro, `\@therearefigures`.

```
\g@addto@macro\figure{\@ifundefined{so@therearefigures}
  {\immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\gdef\string\so@list@figures{1}}%
   \newcommand\@therearefigures{1}} {}}
```

That's about all it takes; when latex is re-run, the aux file will be read in and all definitions executed. Our implementation of `\autolistfigures` simply checks if `\so@list@figures` is defined.

```
\newcommand\autolistfigures{\@ifundefined{so@list@figures} {} {\listoffigures}}
```

Note that the macro we write out (`\so@list@figures`) must be distinct from the macro we use to control the writing (`\so@therearefigures`); if we used the same macro, it would write itself back out to the aux file even if the LaTeX file no longer contains any figures!