# aux file being ignored

Tags: auxiliary-files

I'd like to make a document which looks different each time it is built. I thought this would be pretty easy to do using the `aux` file; however, it seems I am misunderstanding something very basic. For a small proof-of-concept, here is a document that I thought would produce something different on its second run than on its first:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\a{never ran}
\begin{document}
\a
\makeatletter\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\def\string\a{ran}}\makeatother
\end{document}
```

After running `pdflatex test`, I can see that `test.pdf` indeed contains "never ran", and `test.aux` contains:

```
\relax 
\def\a{ran}
```

However, running `pdflatex test` a second time changes neither file. Why not? What should I change so that the document contains `ran` on the second run?

Comment: Don't define single letter macros - especially not without checking whether they already exist!!

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/273116/4427

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need `\gdef` as the `.aux` file is read in inside a group. At least, I think that's why. Certainly, `\gdef` works.

I changed the name of the command to avoid the complications which ensued from overwriting an existing one. In general, very short macro names - especially single letters - are unsafe and unwise. At the very least, you should ensure that they do not already exist rather than simply redefining them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\abacus{never ran}
\begin{document}
\abacus
\makeatletter
\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\gdef\string\abacus{ran}}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Make it a global definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\hasruncheck{never ran}
\begin{document}
    \hasruncheck
    \makeatletter\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\gdef\string\hasruncheck{ran}}\makeatother
\end{document}
```