# Tutorial: Low-Level Basic Implementation of an Asynchronous Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, auxiliary-files, write, tutorials

<sub>**Closely Related:**

- [Mimicking LaTeX's "table of contents" functionality](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273098/mimicking-latexs-table-of-contents-functionality)</sub>

Using `documentclass{minimal}`, what is the shortest way to write a low-level asynchronous `Table of Contents`, (without `minitoc`, etc.)?

I am hoping to understand the low level API functionality.  (I already know how to use the higher level packages, (`tocloft`, `minitoc`, etc).

Currently, I have created a "wrapper" around `tocloft` with an easier to use interface.  However, Eventually I would like to remove that dependency.

**Note:** *I am using the term `Asynchronous Table of Contents` in the sense of a dynamic artifact that is generated as input files are read, (`\chapter` headings and so on), rather than a static table that is defined and rendered manually.*

This question really is related to how to use the `write` command, or how to use some other asynchronous method to dynamically generate a basic Table of Contents.

**Pseudocode:**

```
\ChapterMacroDefinition  % Is this where the `\write` magic occurs?
\TableOfContentsPlaceHolder % Is there an "End Document" handler?
\Chapter{My First Chapter}
 ... Chapter One Contents
\Chapter{My Second Chapter}
 ... Chapter Two Contents
```

**Notes:** *This is apart from any formatting or section levels, etc.*

Comment: Why are you using `minimal`? It's essentially a test class. Are you interested in the detail of how TOCs work, or is this a more practical question?

Comment: @JosephWright - It is more of a detail question, rather than practical.  I am hoping to understand how the API works.  I can't find documentation on it.

Comment: Asynchronous??  Do you mean, like, writing chapter info to the `aux` and `toc` files on the first compiler pass, and then reading the `aux` and `toc` files in on the second compiler pass?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by async toc? Isn't this what the default `\tableofcontents ` does? Just drop the minimal class

Comment: @daleif - Yes, it is what the normal `\tableofcontents` does.  As mentioned in the previous comments, I am trying to understand the low level API functionality.  (I already know how to use the higher level packages, (`tocloft`, `minitoc`, etc).

Comment: Start with basic code: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{HERE}
\end{document}` and compile it **ONCE**.  Then, look at the output, and look at the `aux` file, and look at the `toc` file.  Then compile it **AGAIN**.  See how it works?